# System.NotSupportedException: Character set 'utf8mb3' is not supported by .Net Framework

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to run a server with a MySQL Database, however I keep getting this huge error and I am not sure why.

````
[21:15:49,107] Server Properties Lookup: Error While Initialization
DOL.Database.DatabaseException: Table DOL.Database.ServerProperty is not registered for Database Connection...
   at DOL.Database.ObjectDatabase.SelectAllObjects[TObject]()
   at DOL.GS.ServerProperties.Properties.get_AllDomainProperties()
   at DOL.GS.ServerProperties.Properties.InitProperties()
   at DOL.GS.GameServer.InitComponent(Action componentInitMethod, String text)```

also this error

[21:15:35,991] ExecuteSelectImpl: UnHandled Exception for Select Query "DESCRIBE `Specialization`"
System.NotSupportedException: Character set 'utf8mb3' is not supported by .Net Framework.
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.CharSetMap.GetCharacterSet(DBVersion version, String charSetName)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlField.SetFieldEncoding()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetColumnData(MySqlField field)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetColumnsData(MySqlField[] columns)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetColumns(Int32 count)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ResultSet.LoadColumns(Int32 numCols)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ResultSet..ctor(Driver d, Int32 statementId, Int32 numCols)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.Close()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ResetReader()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at DOL.Database.SQLObjectDatabase.ExecuteSelectImpl(String SQLCommand, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Action`1 Reader)```
````

Comment: "I am trying to run a server with a MySQL Database" Did you mean that you were trying to connect to MySQL server from C# application? If that is the case, try using MySqlConnector package instead of MySql.Data. MySqlConnector  supports utf8mb3. That worked for me in similar case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my case I had installed `10.6.4-MariaDB` that came by default with `utf8mb3`.

I got the same error when trying to read tables.

I had fixed it by changing all charset settings in MariaDB configuration to `utf8mb4`.

Then dumping my database and importing it again. This time specifying `utf8mb4` when creating the database.

So the normal `SELECT`,`UPDATE` queries were working fine, no more error.

But I kept getting an error when my application was calling stored procedures.

I think maybe that was because the stored procedures are saved into the `information_schema` database, that was still `utf8mb3` and I could not find a way to change it to `utf8mb4`.

After losing a lot of time trying to implement some weird workarounds, I had run into this bug report:

**MariaDB 10.6 cannot be used from C# client applications**:
https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-26105?attachmentViewMode=list

One of the users there says:

> The system character set is used only internally by MariaDB and does not need to be changed. In my client program written in C# here is what I did after connecting to make it work with MariaDB 10.6:

```
MySqlCommand setcmd = new MySqlCommand("SET character_set_results=utf8", conn);
int n = setcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
setcmd.Dispose();
```

> in this command utf8 was defaulted to utf8mb4 by MariaDB due to the old_mode setting. That is the results charset that was causing problem with my program.

So I ended up adding this in my VB project just before executing my stored procedures:

```
Dim sqlCommand As New MySqlCommand
sqlCommand.Connection = _MySqlCn
sqlCommand.CommandText = "SET character_set_results=utf8"
sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

This fixed the error for me.

Also, this is what I had previously changed in MariaDB server configuration:

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8mb4

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8mb4

# this is read by the standalone daemon and embedded servers
[server]

# this is only for the mysqld standalone daemon
[mysqld]

old_mode=
character-set-server = utf8mb4
character-set-client=utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8mb4'
```

Comment: In my case changing package from MySql.Data to MySqlConnector worked (staying with utf8mb3 in database settings). MySqlConnector package supports utf8mb3.

Answer (score 41):

There is [an update available to the **MySQL Connector/NET**](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-net/commit/16ad749586b0e5eb1aad127e3744096692e4a6ae#diff-f422179f18fcab216691dde319e2c13c0a615a2474d2d8e227bdc15b3ed52f50).

After updating to version 8.0.28 (NuGet package [`MySql.Data`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/)) everything is working again.

Comment: This is the short and quick answer! Worked for me as well. Thanks

Comment: exactly! I installed MySQL Server - the latest version, but did not update the Nuget package of client software, which was 8.0.19. After updating it an error has gone. Thanks!

Comment: The same worked for me. I updated nuget package version to be the same as mysql docker image version . Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, taking me left and right and no where. That's a real answer

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a solution.
Source :
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8239/how-to-easily-convert-utf8-tables-to-utf8mb4-in-mysql-5-5

Change your CHARACTER SET AND COLLATE to utf8mb4.

For each database:

```
ALTER DATABASE
    database_name
    CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4
    COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

For each table:

```
ALTER TABLE
    table_name
    CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
    COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

For each column:

```
ALTER TABLE
    table_name
    CHANGE column_name column_name
    VARCHAR(191)
    CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
    COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Worked for me with Powershell and MariaDB 10.6.
Hope this will help ;)

Answer (score 1):

In my case *(MariaDB 10.6)* helped changing `character-set-server` in ...\MariaDB 10.6\data\my.ini from **utf8** to **utf8mb4**. Now everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

For .NET CORE 5.0, I had to upgrade 3 NuGet Packages from v.5.0.0 to v.5.0.13:

1. MySql.EntityFrameworkCore
2. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
3. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools

Answer (score 1):

I "solved" this by abandoning Oracle's MySQL Connector/Net and rewrote the application to use [MySqlConnector](https://mysqlconnector.net/). It was very little work, but I also had to rewrite everything about the user management since I had it depend on MySql.Web, and this was not as easy.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by changing the MySQL Connector/NET version to **8.0.28**

[Download do MySQL Connector/NET](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-net/)

Answer (score 0):

For those rare instances where upgrading our MySql Connector/Net is not an option, you can download the source code, alter code to ignore utf8mb3, compile, then re-deploy.

---

I had the same issue with the MySql Connector/Net `6.7.9` and a MySql `8.0.28` installation on AWS Managed RDS. We had minor and patch versions enabled, so when our MySql instance updated to `8.0.29`, everything crashed (that's when MySql decided to treat utf8 as utf8mb3 which the 6.7.9 connector does not know).
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-29.html#mysqld-8-0-29-charset

We tried to alter the proper MySql server variables via AWS and converting all the tables, views, and dropping/re-creating routines with the utf8mb4 encoding in a sandbox environment, but that did not fix the issue as there is one critical value that AWS does not allow you to change, `character-set-system`.

Ideally, we'd like to upgrade our Net/Connector, however, upgrading was not an option as it required us to migrate from EntityFramework 4 to 5. The amount of work to do this in our huge project was not an option (we are already in the process of partitioning parts off as domain-based microservices).

Our solution was to download the source code for 6.7.9 and change one line of code that checked for `utf8mb3` and forced it to `utf8mb4`, and this was done in the following GetCharacterSet signature:
https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-net/blob/03fc119558f7c70b13a46b12718e0ad5856d8e7c/Source/MySql.Data/CharSetMap.cs#L50

This was fairly straight forward, and it allowed us to leave the encoding/charset of our database (and parameters) alone.