# I am unable to connect visual basic to MYSQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net, mysql-workbench, mysql-connector

Hi I am trying to connect visual basic to MYSQL but I am having two errors. One is when clicking on the drop-down list of databases it doesn't show any database; instead it displays an error saying UNABLE TO RETRIEVE LIST OF DATABASES, with that i add the database manually by typing it down and click on OK. Now I want to expand the tables folder on the server explorer and another error pops up which is CHARACTER SET UTF8MB3 IS NOT SUPPORTED BY .NET FRAMEWORK.

[Error 1 - character set utf8mb3 is not supported by .net framework](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHRyr.jpg)

[Error 2 - unable to retrieve list of databases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mslRO.jpg)

I have searched for countless solutions on youtube and here on stack but to no avail. I even tried to downgrade MYSQL versions hoping it would solve the problem but I am still getting the same errors. I am using visual basic 2019 and MYSQL workbench, the server is up and running. I am stuck in these two errors and cannot find a solution. If anyone could shed a light here and guide me on the errors. I have attached two screenshots of the errors.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [System.NotSupportedException: Character set 'utf8mb3' is not supported by .Net Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645324/system-notsupportedexception-character-set-utf8mb3-is-not-supported-by-net-f)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @deripirscher I checked that post before posting a question and followed the answers but it didn't solve my question