# How to resolve KeyNotFoundException for MySql.Data.dll in .NET 2.0 with Maria10.6 version?

Tags: mysql, .net, mariadb, executereader, keynotfoundexception

Currently, I am using both of .NET 2.0 and .NET 4.0  Framework websites.
All Websites are using MySql.Data.dll 6.8.3 ver.

I found the reason for '**KeyNotFoundException**' from these references that indicate unsupported chatset is the problem.

- References
  #1. https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-26105?attachmentViewMode=list
  #2. [System.NotSupportedException: Character set 'utf8mb3' is not supported by .Net Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645324/system-notsupportedexception-character-set-utf8mb3-is-not-supported-by-net-f)*

So I changed the mysql connector version.

- References
  #1. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-net/en/news-8-0-28.html

.NET 4.0 websites are working by

1. changing MySql.Data.dll from 6.8.3 to 8.0.33
2. install .NET 4.6.2 Frameworks
3. edit machine.config file.

**But the problem is .NET 2.0 websites because MySql.Data.dll 8.0.33. ver supports .NET Framework 4.6.2 above**

I am trying to solve instead of changing website to .NET 4.0.

I changed Table Charset utf8mb3 to utf8mb4.

```
ALTER [TABLE] CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Using SQL scripts are solved but I got same problem('KeyNotFoundException') by using procedures.

```
Database database = new GernericDatabase(base.GetConnectionMainDB(), GetMySQLDbProvider());

// **Worked Well**
query = "select * from [table]";
DbCommand cmd = database.GetSqlStringCommand(query);
cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

```
// **Worked Wrong **
DbConnection con = data.CreateConnection();
DbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = [procedureName];
cmd.ExecuteReader(); // KeyNotFoundException
```

I didn't the reason why error from using procedures.

If I use SQL script
SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE [procedure name].

SQL script results
character_set_client : utf8mb4
collation_connection : utf8mb4_gerneral_ci
Database Collation : utf8mb4_gerneral_ci

Is there any way that I can use .net 2.0 framework with mysql db ver 10.6?

Summary
#1 Trying to solve .NET 4.0 Framework

1. changed MySql.Data.dll version to 8.0.33 - it works

#2 Trying to solve .NET 2.0 Framework

1. changed Table charset - SQL commands worked but procedure didn't work
2. changed MySql.Data.dll version to 8.0.33 - does not support on .NET 2.0 Framework